# NodeMCU run sensor code while listening for wifi input?

Tags: wifi, nodemcu

Is it possible to have code running while also listening for local inputs via ip address? I thought it would go in the 'while' portion but I presume that only responses when the ip is loaded.

```
void loop() {

  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (!client) {
    return;
  }
  while (!client.available()) {
    delay(1);   
  }
  String query = client.readStringUntil('\r');
  client.flush();

  if (query.indexOf("/open") != -1)  {
    open_fast();
  } else if (query.indexOf("/close") != -1)  {
    close_fast();
  }

  sensor = analogRead(A0);
  sensor = map(sensor, 0, 1023, 0, full);

  Serial.print(sensor);
  Serial.print("  ");
  Serial.println(pos);

  if (sensor > pos) {
    open_slow();
    delay(1000);
  } else if (sensor < pos) {
    close_slow();
    delay(1000);
  }
  delay(100);

}
```

Comment: instead of`if (!client) {
    return;
  }` use `if (client) { /* handle client */ }`?

Comment: @Juraj What does that do?

Comment: take a coding course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that at

```
while (!client.available()) {
  delay(1);
}
// your wifi code
```

you wait for a wifi event and in that time you obviously can't read the sensor. Just poll for incoming requests by doing it like

```
if (client.available()) {
  // your wifi code
}
```

This way your loop skips the wifi-routine if there is nothing to do and proceeds with reading the sensor.

As mikrocontrollers usually don't run a OS, you don't have multitasking which you have to implement yourself.
Generally you have to avoid using delay loops when you want several tasks being executed "parallely".

Comment: The difference between "if" and "while" in this situation, does it negatively effect the wifi or mcu by polling the internet in any different way or are they basically the same?

Comment: `client.available()` just checks if there are any requests in the esp's input buffer, the actual communication has allready taken place at that time and is handled by the esp's hardware. But there is a fundamental difference between `if` and `while`: `if` is only a single test for wifi activity, `while` delays your `loop` **until** wifi activity and is not what you want.